# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) for Update_Attribute Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, update-attributes, argument-error

I am creating a recurring event app where certain users (streamers) can schedule recurring weekly events (streams) and other users (viewers) can follow them. The result is a personalized weekly calendar detailing when all followed streamers' events begin and end.

[image]

However, because viewers can follow an infinite number of streamers and therefore the resulting calendar would look like a hot mess. So I added a boolean attribute to the relationships table that indicates whether the relationship has been favorited.

```
  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "follower_id"
    t.integer "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "favorited", default: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
  end
```

This way, viewers will have a second personalized calendar that will show only favorited streamers' events.

I already have a follow and unfollow method that successfully create and destroy a relationship between viewer and streamer, but I'm having trouble successfully updating an existing relationship from unfavorited to favorited.

```
test "should favorite and unfavorite a streamer" do
    yennifer = users(:yennifer)
    cirilla = users(:cirilla)
    yennifer.follow(cirilla)
    yennifer.favorite(cirilla)     #user_test.rb:151
end
```

The testing suite returns the following error and I can't figure out what the missing argument is.

```
["test_should_favorite_and_unfavorite_a_streamer", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x0000000006125da8 @name="UserTest">, 0.16871719993650913]
 test_should_favorite_and_unfavorite_a_streamer#UserTest (0.17s)
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
            app/models/relationship.rb:11:in `favorite'
            app/models/user.rb:124:in `favorite'
            test/models/user_test.rb:151:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

  27/27: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.82473s
27 tests, 71 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

**User.rb**

```
# Follows a user
def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

# Unfollows a user
def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
end

def favorite(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).favorite     #user.rb:124
end

def unfavorite(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).unfavorite
end
```

**Relationships.rb**

```
def favorite
    update_attribute(favorited: true)     #relationship.rb:11
end

def unfavorite
    update_attribute(favorited: false)
end
```

Can someone please help me in identifying the missing argument and fixing this problem. Thank you.

Comment: The raised error is fairly clear. The [`update_attribute`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) method expects 2 arguments and you are passing one (a hash). Change it to `update_attribute(:favorited, true)`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a stupid typo but I couldn't see it.

Comment: In my case just update did the job instead of update_attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment on this answer is correct, so I don't know why this person posted as a comment rather than an answer. update_attribute takes two arguments and you are passing it a single hash argument. Your "favorite" method is the equivalent of 
`update_attribute({favorited: true})` when you really want `update_attribute(:favorited, true)`